# I need help in uploading a file to a folder on my server and then adding the file details to a database

Tags: sql, file-upload, razor, webmatrix

I am trying to make a page for my site where users can upload a game, give it a name then the file gets uploaded to a folder on my site and the file name and game name get added to my sql database but it gives an error saying: "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" when i try to run it.

My code for this page is:

```
@{
var db= Database.Open("Games");
var sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM Games";
var data = db.Query(sqlQ);   

}
@{
 var fileName = "";
if (IsPost) {
    var fileSavePath = "";
    var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
    fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
    fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedFiles/" +
      fileName);
    uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
}
 var GameName="";
 var GameGenre="";
 var GameYear="";
 if(IsPost){
GameName=Request["formName"];
var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO Games (Name, file_path) VALUES (@0, @1)";
db.Execute(SQLINSERT, GameName, fileName);
Response.Redirect("default.cshtml");
   }
}

<h1 >Add a new game to the database</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
<p>Name:<input type="text" name="formName" /></p>
@FileUpload.GetHtml(
    initialNumberOfFiles:1,
    allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
    includeFormTag:true,
    uploadText:"Add")
```

The error page says that the problem is with line 11 but i don't know what to change.

Comment: did you tried regular file input instead of @FileUpload?

Comment: I think you need to go read up on ASP.NET MVC3 to understand Controllers, Models and Views.  Most of this code should be in a Controller, *not* in a View.

Answer (score 1):

As Hightechrider has correctly said, your code should reside in Controllers, not in views. The exception you are getting is because Request.Files is an empty array, so when you're trying to access [0] element, you get an IndexWasOutOfRange error.

I'd recommend you reading the following [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) for uploading files in ASP.NET MVC. It presents an easier, more consistent and flexible model by putting the code in the controller action. Basically, all code boils down to this:

1. You create an upload form with submit button and file input.
2. You create an action that accepts HttpPostedFileBase variable.

Comment: He is not using ASP.NET MVC. He uses WebMatrix and he wrongly tagged his question.

Comment: I'd recommend going to http://www.asp.net/get-started ; I personally prefer developing in ASP.NET MVC, there is a bunch of tutorials that get you up to speed like http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store

Answer (score 0):

You must set the proper enctype to your form if you want to upload files:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Sorry then, I couldn't see it anywhere in the code you have shown.